# How can I force a FireMonkey TComboEdit to show its drop down programatically

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have a TComboEdit in a FireMonkey application.

In VCL I could do something like this:

```
  SendMessage(myComboEdit.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, 1, 0);
```

Of course, messaging in FMX works differently than in VCL so this trick appears not to work under FMX. (i.e., it's not exposed to us).

How can I coax my TCombiEdit to show the drop down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the dropdown of a [`TComboEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.ComboEdit.TComboEdit) control you can use the [`DropDown`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.ComboEdit.TComboEditBase.DropDown) method like this

```
 ComboEdit1.DropDown;
```

or send a `PM_DROPDOWN` message using the `SendMessage` method of the model.

```
 ComboEdit1.Model.SendMessage(PM_DROPDOWN);
```

Comment: Works. I've noted that the DropDown method is a toggle on and off. So I needed to add an "If not ComboEdit1.DroppedDown then" to prevent it from closing an already open DropDown.

Comment: Also, "ComboEdit1.Model.SendMessage(PM_DROPDOWN" seems to act as a toggle on DropDown as well. It's partner "ComboEdit1.Model.SendMessage(PM_CLOSE_DROPDOWN" does not, so you could also do an explicit close, and then toggle  DropDown as well.